# Can't locate SDK folder in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I have been using Eclipse for over a month now, and have been developing an app. It has been working fine until now. It gives me the error: Cannot find SDK folder '`C:\Users\bax\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\.`'  It was working fine earlier today. 
What could be the cause of this? Any ideas? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: go to Windows-> preferences -> android and browse SDK location like C:\Users\admin\android-sdks

Comment: I did that. It says "Value must be an existing directory."

Comment: I think you have change the sdk location. Please check manually  whether your sdk is there or not. if it is there then just give me the path of that sdk where it is located. and i will saw more on it.

Comment: I have it working now. Just had to re-add the directory location. What would cause something like that out of no where?

Comment: check if the android-sdk directory and the required files exists on your desktop or wherever u extracted the ADT Bundle.

Comment: Simple, Again download ADT bundle and extract it, after that locate the path of android-sdk directory in eclipse->windows->preference->(right panel)->android

Comment: I had that same problem. I finally figured out that the reason it would happen is when I would move the folder (either accidentally or on purpose). The problem is that when it is downloaded it saves the path. When it is moved the path isn't updated. It's a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I just unzipped the SDK bundle on the location  where get Error "Value must be an existing directory." and its working good. I think main issue is all about path.